# Ubuntu 21.10 boots to black screen

Tags: xorg, login, ubuntu-gnome, wayland, 21.10

Yestarday I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 to Ubuntu 21.10 but when I rebooted my laptop (Asus X505BA) and tried to login with Xorg I got a blackscreen. After that, I restarted my laptop again and I tried to login with Wayland but I got a blackscreen too.

I thought this could be caused by an upgrade error so I reinstalled Ubuntu 21.10 but the problem persists. However, I can "avoid" this problem if I login to text mode and then run startx. Unfortunately if I do this, the system starts in low resolution and some applications don't work.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: You may want to report it. I do not know for sure it is a bug but it still might be a good idea. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: What video card do you have? If it's Nvidia, have you updated the driver? Can you get to the GRUB menu?

Comment: The laptop has AMD integranted graphics. I can get to GRUB menu without troubles.

Comment: At the GRUB menu, select the desired boot item, then hit "e" to enter edit mode, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x or F10 to continue booting. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema It worked, thank you.

Comment: Hold up a sec. That's not a permanent fix. Only a test. It means that your AMD driver is probably out of date for 21.10. Download/install a newer version. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I only have installed the open source drivers provided by Ubuntu and apt doesn't report any updates available. Should I install the privative drivers?

Comment: Yes. Try the non-open-source drivers, or you may need to go to the AMD site and check for newer drivers that are compatible with 21.10. Please keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema Unfortunately I just found out that AMD doesn't provide Linux drivers for my APU model.

Comment: Does the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates show any choices?

Comment: @heynnema No, it says "No additional drivers available".

Comment: Are you still booting with nomodeset?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, should I reboot whitout it?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to continue using nomodeset, until such time you can find a 21.10-compatible video driver update. Add nomodeset into /etc/default/grub and then do `sudo update-grub`, so you won't have to manually enter it at each boot.

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and then go to the ASUS web site and see if there's a newer BIOS available for your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to many bug reports it's a kernel bug in kernel version 5.13. Upgrading to kernel version 5.14 or downgrading to kernel version 5.12 solves the problem.

Comment: How can I upgrade the kernel on recovery mode

Answer (score 3):

From the comments...

Your AMD video driver appears to not be compatible with 21.10. A newer driver is not apparent.

Booting with `nomodeset` allows the machine to fully boot.

Edit /etc/default/grub and find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", and then do `sudo update-grub`, so you won't have to manually do this at boot time.

Comment: When doing this the blank screen changes to "Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes" & "Failed to start Light Display Manager". Previously I tried installing an older Nvidia 390 driver using the tty console. Would you suggest using the free default driver.

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat Please start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to install different graphic drivers. My laptop has an amd graphic card and dedicated nvidia. It's just annoying to do this manually after every ubuntu upgrade. Second time now... Ubuntu could add a check or warning to do this before the upgrade or automatically.

Now I need to `CTRL+ALT+1` after boot and do it manually in cli instead in a gui.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a kernel bug ! It works with a 5.13.0-19, but fails with the 5.13.0-35, which is currently (March 2022) the official version attached to any  21.10 *buntu. Either use the initial 5.13.0-19 or upgrade to 5.14.* or higher (I'm running a 5.17 rc7 and have no problem).