# Black Screen after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: nvidia, display, 22.04

Upgraded from Ubuntu 20 to 22.04 on an AMD 7302 16-Core desktop machine with Nvidia GP107GL (Quadro P620) graphics card, and DELL u3415W display (3440x1440). After BIOS information, just get a black screen.  I can ssh into the Ubuntu machine but cannot use the console. Have upgraded (via ssh terminal) Nvidia drivers to the recommended 515 (installed 470 driver didn't work now). Tried lots of things but nothing seems to work -- just dead ends.  Also cannot remote-desktop either -- get the "establish remote desktop" connection (Windows 11 machine) and then immediately get a "Oh no! Something went wrong" with "logout" button -- might be a separate problem but I guess it is possible it is related to the display problem.  Just in case, I did uninstall, reinstall, re-configure, re-start  xrdp. Didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 21.10 boots to black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369409/ubuntu-21-10-boots-to-black-screen)

Comment: I'm guessing grub mistakenly doesn't recognize your video mode _or_ it's not turning on the screen backlight (this often happens to me after the system sleeps, but not on boot). Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-to-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution

Comment: Auspex -- thanks for the info. Unfortunately, didn't solve my problem. Thankfully can ssh into machine and do not generally need the console. But I know there will come a day when I do!! Until then, getting real work done via ssh and trying different things when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved -- I uninstalled nvidia drivers and reinstalled nouveau driver. However; I am wondering if something was wrong with my ubuntu-desktop install versus my driver. Using information from:

[How to switch from nvidia to nouveau drivers on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032357/how-to-switch-from-nvidia-to-nouveau-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)

and another site (I can't find it now) that said removing nvidia drivers sometimes messes up ubuntu-desktop, I did:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Then:
sudo apt install nouveau-firmware

Then a reboot.   Finally -- after probably two dozen reboots and various edits (which I now remember I still have GRUB_FXMODE=3440x1440 in my /etc/default/grub file (though it did nothing on its own) --  I can use/see my Ubuntu desktop console and sign-in directly (versus having to ssh into the machine all the time).

I am speculating that this "fix" had more to do with the ubuntu-desktop install than it did the drivers (though I may be wrong) because the type of install messages I got seemed more like it hadn't been installed before, rather than being repaired now (wish I had looked more closely when I did it).  I could have been an nvidia driver (470) that worked with 20 but not with 22.04 and it could have been the recommended nvidia driver (515) also did not work.  Or it could have been the ubuntu-desktop install...